# Build array by string name OR make multiple array by string values

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, array-push

I want to build a array or multiple array by breaking the main array , and my array is like ,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => string1   
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 66
    [5] => 34
    [6] => string1
    [7] => aww
    [8] => brr
    [9] => string3
    [10] => xas

)
```

So basically by the value **'string1'** i want to make a **new array or first array** which has **only** those three values (1,2,3) and same for **string2** and **string3**,So each array has its values(three).
Please help me to build this.
**Note: those all string names will be static.**

Thank you in advance.

Result should me like:

```
string1 array:  
<pre>Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 66
    [5] => 34
)

string2 array:  
<pre>Array
(
    [1] => aww
    [2] => brr
)

string3 array:  
<pre>Array
(
    [1] => xas
)
```

Comment: Can show us how exactly the result should be?

Comment: yeah sure.Let me update my Question again.

Comment: so you want 'string1' as key and next numbers as values?

Comment: It would be a **better idea** to look at how you created this array in the first place and create it there as you actually want it to be

Comment: Will there always be 4 occurances in each group i.e. `string1,1,2,3`

Comment: So, if you want to separate the array by those string names rather than into groups of the same size, are `string1`, `string2`, etc. just for example, or will the values actually be those strings?

Comment: Yes.But size will be never same.I am updating again my question for better understanding.sorry for it.

Comment: I think that re-arranging everything in one big multi-dimensional array is a better idea than generating loads of new variables that after this re-ordering might or might not exist.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @jeroen : i have update my question.

Comment: @jeroen :  One array will be fine too. It will be fine if those string name comes as key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This I think will get you what you want.

> It does assume that the first entry in the old array will be a keyword!

```
$old = array('string1',1,2,3,66,34,'string2','aww','brr','string3','xas');
$new = array();

$keywords = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
$last_keyword = '';

foreach ($old as $o) {
    if ( in_array($o, $keywords) ) {
        $last_keyword = $o;        
    } else {
        $new[$last_keyword][] = $o;
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

It creates a new array like this

```
Array
(
    [string1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 66
            [4] => 34
        )

    [string2] => Array
        (
            [0] => aww
            [1] => brr
        )

    [string3] => Array
        (
            [0] => xas
        )

)
```

> However I still maintain that it would be better to go back to where the original array gets created and look to amend that process rather than write a fixup for it

Comment: Works awesome.Thank you for help.